# Dynamic setting of form_tag submit destination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

Is it possible to set the location you want to submit a form to dynamically at runtime with a form_tag?  What I have is a shared partial view that is used to filter data on several screens.  The view contains several different form fields and a submit button, so the UI for these controls is the same for all the screens that use it, thus the shared partial view.  The difference is that I want the submit to go back to a different location depending upon which page the partial view is contained in.  Is there someway to pass the destination in via the render tag like the following?

```
<%= render 'shared/event_filter', :dest => event_path %>
```

and then consume it within the partial view as follows?

```
<%= form_tag(:dest, :method => "get") do %>
```

The above code doesn't work, it gives me a nomethod error on the :dest in the form_tag, but I was just putting in this question to help illustrate what I was trying to do.

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be looking for something along these lines:

```
<%= render :partial => 'shared/event_filter', :locals => {:form_action => event_path} %>
```

Which just renders the partial named `shared/_event_filter.html.erb` and passes in a variable called `form_action` with value of `event_path`.

Then inside your partial:

```
<%= form_tag form_action, :method => "get" do %>
    <!-- snip -->
<% end %>
```